# What is the complementary operation of extractSingle?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

For `ember-data 1.0.0-beta6`, I have this serializer:

```
SettingsApp.CompanySerializer = SettingsApp.MetaRESTSerializer.extend({
    extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id, requestType) {
        var company = payload;
        company.company.nodeType = payload.company.type;
        company.company.invoiceLanguage = payload.company['invoice-language'];
        company.company.companyLanguage = payload.company['company-language'];
        company.company.paymentMethod   = payload.company['payement-method'];
        // TODO: delete original properties?
        return this._super(store, type, company, id, requestType);
    }
});
```

How can I do the inverse operation? That is, before the model is going to be POSTed to the server, how can I map the model to the json?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three hooks you'll want to look at, the code can be located here https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/serializers/rest_serializer.js#L760

#### Serialize

````
    ## Tweaking the Default JSON

    If you just want to do some small tweaks on the default JSON,
    you can call super first and make the tweaks on the returned
    JSON.

    ```js
    App.PostSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
      serialize: function(record, options) {
        var json = this._super(record, options);

        json.subject = json.title;
        delete json.title;

        return json;
      }
    });
    ```

    @method serialize
    @param record
    @param options
  */
  serialize: function(record, options) {
    return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
  },
````

#### Serialize Into Hash

````
  /**
    You can use this method to customize the root keys serialized into the JSON.
    By default the REST Serializer sends camelized root keys.
    For example, your server may expect underscored root objects.

    ```js
    App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.RESTSerializer.extend({
      serializeIntoHash: function(data, type, record, options) {
        var root = Ember.String.decamelize(type.typeKey);
        data[root] = this.serialize(record, options);
      }
    });
    ```

    @method serializeIntoHash
    @param {Object} hash
    @param {subclass of DS.Model} type
    @param {DS.Model} record
    @param {Object} options
  */
  serializeIntoHash: function(hash, type, record, options) {
    var root = Ember.String.camelize(type.typeKey);
    hash[root] = this.serialize(record, options);
  },
````

#### Serialize Polymorphic Type

```
  /**
    You can use this method to customize how polymorphic objects are serialized.
    By default the JSON Serializer creates the key by appending `Type` to
    the attribute and value from the model's camelcased model name.

    @method serializePolymorphicType
    @param {DS.Model} record
    @param {Object} json
    @param {Object} relationship
  */
  serializePolymorphicType: function(record, json, relationship) {
    var key = relationship.key,
        belongsTo = get(record, key);
    key = this.keyForAttribute ? this.keyForAttribute(key) : key;
    json[key + "Type"] = Ember.String.camelize(belongsTo.constructor.typeKey);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. what are polymorphic types? Collections? Heterogeneous collections?